# Flutter : Apple Pay button isn't showing in real Device using pay Plugin

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, applepay, invisible, google-pay

I want to use in app purchase, that's why I using [Pay](https://pub.dev/packages/pay) plugin in my flutter app. Everything is fine when I check it in my simulator but when I run it on real iPhone button is not showing. Here is screenshot of real and virtual device with same code base.

***Simulator -***

[image]

***Real Device -***

[image]

Now, help me someone. How can I solved this ?

Comment: Wrap it in to a `SizedBox` with assigning `width `and `height`

Comment: @SubairK it's not design problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason that Apple Pay button is not visible when you test it on a real device is probable because **you haven't added any cards in your apple wallet**.

If that is the case then you will need to **add a testing account in your apple developer's testers sandbox** and then logout your apple id in your iphone and signin with the new testing account and then you'll be able to add some dummy cards in the wallet and after that you'll be able to see the apple pay button.

**You can follow the apple pay sandbox testing documentations**

**[Apple Pay Sandbox Testing](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/)**

Comment: Mine also facing the same issue. Since I'm out of the countries listed as suppoted, how can I test it.

Answer (score 1):

@ahmed saeed's answer is correct and here's a more detailed step-by-step tuto

The Apple Pay button will not be visible on a real device until you add a test card to your apple wallet, and in order to be able to do that follow these steps:

- Create a tester account with Sandbox Apple ID (use a fresh email)
- Make sure you set the account's country to the US (to avoid any confusion)
- Logout from apple id on your real device if any is logged in
- Login with the tester account you've made
- Set your device region to the US
- Add a shipping address that is in the US also (Settings > Apple ID > Payment & Shipping)
- Go to [Apple Pay Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/) and choose one of the testing cards in the list provided by Apple and add it to your wallet (Wallet app)

And you're all set, the Apple Pay button should appear now since you've set your Wallet (Make sure to log out and log in again after any country changes).

**Keep in mind that we're setting everything to the US to avoid any countries confusion, I recommend testing it with US settings and after you can test other countries**, so make sure to set the country field for:

1. Sandbox tester
2. Real device's region
3. Shipping address
4. Test card that matches US

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add test user account in apple developer's **testers sandbox** **in order to test on real device** with a test card, refer to [this blog](https://hassanannajjar.medium.com/how-to-use-apple-pay-with-flutter-87b56e654313):

> 3- add tester account to apple developer to use testing card in real device:
>
> - open tester sandbox link App Store Connect (apple.com) and add the new email.

**only these countries are supported untill the time of writing this answer:**

Australia
Canada
China mainland
Hong Kong
Taiwan
France
Ireland
Italy
Japan
New Zealand
Russia
Singapore
Spain
United Kingdom
United States

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).